# Parameters and Functions Problems in C++

Tags: c++, c, function, parameters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int agrc, char* argv[])
{
    int num = atof(argv[1]);

    *par_ou_impar(num);

    return 0;
}

char *par_ou_impar(int aux)
{
    return (aux % 2 == 0) ? "par" : "impar";
}
```

I want to create a program to receive a parameter int in function `char *par_ou_impar` and if it's even returns `"par"` else returns `"impar"`.

I dont understand what is wrong but it says me the following errors:

```
'par_ou_impar' : 'char *(int)' differs in levels of indirection from 'int ()' - 
                                          line 14 illegal indirection - line 8
```

Comment: [Clang's errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/417488b973a667f1) are maybe more helpful.

Comment: You need to pick either C++ or C, as the answers are different.

Comment: I find it is really funny C++ guys refuse to use any C techniques, even they are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [`atof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) converts from a `const char*` to `double`, while [`atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) is the corresponding "C" library function to use to convert to `int`.

Separately, string literals like "par" and "impar" should be returned as `const char*`s, not `char*`s - it's not legal to overwrite their content, and the compiler will complain if you discard `const` implicitly.  `argv[]` can also be `const` too.

Further, you can't call a function from `main()` if it's not at least declared earlier in the translation unit.  So, you must either move the entire `par_ou_impar(int)` function definition above `main()` (the simplest approach), or add a declaration as I've done below....

```
#include <iostream>  // for cerr, cout
#include <cstdlib>   // for atoi

const char* par_ou_impar(int aux);  // declare here, define below

int main(int argc, const char* const argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <number>\n"
                     "reports whether <number> is even\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int num = std::atoi(argv[1]);

    std::cout << par_ou_impar(num) << '\n';

    // no need to return 0 - that's implicit in C++
}

const char* par_ou_impar(int aux)
{
    return (aux % 2 == 0) ? "par" : "impar";
}
```

It's worth being aware that `atoi` doesn't report an error if its argument (above, `argv[1]`) contains trailing non-numeric characters: e.g. `"123x"` yields `123` and ignores `x`, `"-3/2"` yields `-3` and ignores `/2`.  More robust checking for a legal number can be performed as follows:

```
std::istringstream iss(argv[1]);
char c;
if (iss >> num && !(iss >> c))
   ... num was parsed successfully and no trailing non-whitespace ...
else
   ... report the error ...
```

If you happen to use the non-Standard "boost" library, `boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[1])` is a sometimes-convenient alternative, though setting up a `try`/`catch` for a single error check is a bit verbose and clumsy:

```
try
{
    int num = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[1]);
    std::cout << par_ou_impar(num) << '\n';
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "parsing of number from argv[1] failed...\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your error message. These are the changes I needed to make to get it to compile. You need to declare the function prototype before it is called. Also, you should use `const char *` for string literals in C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *par_ou_impar(int aux);

int main(int agrc, char* argv[])
{
    int num = atof(argv[1]);

    *par_ou_impar(num);

    return 0;
}

const char *par_ou_impar(int aux)
{
    return (aux % 2 == 0) ? "par" : "impar";
}
```

You can [test](http://ideone.com/sXMy0f) the code if you want.

Comment: What's with the downvote? Please leave feedback so I can improve.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the function prototype, when you call `par_ou_impar()` in `main()` the compiler doesn't know yet how to call the `par_ou_impar()` function, so you need to give the compiler a hint, you could

1. Move the definition of `par_ou_impar()` before the definition of `main()`.
2. Provide a function prototype, that is, a function declaration before `main()`, a function declaration is simply

   ```
   char *par_ou_impar(int number);
   ```

you have other mistakes in your program, but they are not preventing it from compiling.

My recommendation is to turn on compiler warnings, that will let you find out what the other problems are.